# Not able to see Partitioned attribute in response headers

Tags: third-party-cookies

I am sending a cookie string with Partitioned attribute in order to consume third party cookies for some domain. I can see the partition key in cookie details in application tab but can't see the Partitioned attribute in response headers in network tab.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Does the network tab show the attribute in the response to https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Set-Cookie=a=b;%20SameSite=None;%20Secure;%20Partitioned ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.